# Android Animations - Transform button to FAB

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a button, which i want to transform into a FAB. Please see the below animation for reference. Can someone let me know how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the button is transformed into a FAB. On click it circularly hides and a `ProgressBar` becomes visible and the following screen is circularly revealed. To achieve smoother transitions the views are crossfaded. Please check the following link to see how to use circular reveal/hide in android - http://lgvalle.xyz/2015/06/07/material-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="700"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

It was a simple scale animation.